# How to trim body text (field_body)?

Tags: theming, 8

I've created a view for a node which shows the content as rendered entity. Among others, I output the body field in the twig template:

```
{{ content.field_body }}
```

Now, I'd like to limit the text to 200 characters and put three dots. I've tested three different ways to do that, but nothing has worked. The problem is, that each way counts and trims the HTML characters too.

1: I've added the format "Trimmed" in "Manage display" => The text is limited but not correct. And I do not have the three dots.

2: I've trimmed the text in the twig template. But to count the text I have to render it first. Thereby, twig outputs the text as HTML (I see HTML tags on my page!)

```
{% set text = content.field_body|render %}
{{ text|length > 200 ? text|slice(0, 200) ~ '...' : text }}
```

3: I've tried to solve the problem in template_preprocess_node(). Here I have the same problem with counting the HTML markup too.

```
$body_text = $node->get('field_body')->getValue()[0]['value'];
$trimmed_text = substr($body_text, 0, 200) . '...';
```

How can I trim my text right?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's a few solutions you can try but take note truncating strings with html is generally a bad idea due to having potential unclosed or malformed tags.

**1. Use |raw to output the html as html, may produce malformed tags:**

```
{% set text = content.field_body|render %}
{{ text|length > 200 ? text|slice(0, 200)|raw ~ '...' : text|raw }}
```

**2. Strip html first, cleaner:**

```
{% set text = content.field_body|render|striptags %}
{{ text|length > 200 ? text|slice(0, 200) ~ '...' : text }}
```

**3. Register a twig extension (untested):**

https://gist.github.com/leon/2857883

Another helpful extension you can check out is the Text extension, which helps you prevent chopping up words:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/text.html

Comment: first solution  malformed tags and second solution  strip all html tags.

Comment: @zhilevan yep, as described in the answer.

Comment: @squall3d what is your solution for  slice it without strip htmls?

Comment: @zhilevan usually when I want to display truncated text it's for the purpose of a teaser, where I seldom want html. But if you do need to preserve html, you can try this extension: https://gist.github.com/leon/2857883

Comment: If I use the image in the body field. No 2 , is not working for images. Is there any other code, will print the image as well

Comment: @logeshvaran you can pass a parameter to stiptags so it ignores image tags. e.g.  {{ your_html|striptags('<img>') }} . You can refer to https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/striptags.html

Answer (score 7):

Improvements:

1. if you strip tags you should `|trim` to **get rid of whitespace**
2. **trim on word boundary** - see below `slice()` and `split()`
3. Use **ellipsis** (`&hellip;`) rather than "..."
4. `|raw` the output

`{% set text = content.field_header_intro|render|striptags|trim %}`

`{{ (text|length > 200 ? text|slice(0, 201)|split(' ')|slice(0, -1)|join(' ') ~ '&hellip;' : text)|raw }}`

Comment: `content.field_header_intro|render|striptags|trim` this gives perfect character count.

Answer (score 6):

You can now do this with the [twig_extender](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_extender) module and use `|truncate`.

Here is an example of how to use it in the .twig template, note that I'm also using [twig_field_value](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_field_value):

```
{{ content.field_name|field_value|first['#text']|truncate(15, true, '....') }}
```

*note:*
I usually keep my devel settings (./admin/config/development/devel) set to use ***Symfony var-dumper*** and can figure out the chain with

ie: `{{ devel_dump(content.field_name|field_value) }}`

Answer (score 4):

This is how I handled this.

Example:
**field--node--body--article.html.twig**

```
{% set mode = element['#view_mode'] %}
...
{% for item in items %}
  {% if mode == 'full' %}
    <div{{ attributes.addClass('texto') }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
  {% elseif mode == 'teaser' %}
    {# if there is something about trim_length in field formatter #}
    {% if item.content['#text_summary_trim_length'] %}
      {# first remove html tags then you slice with trim_length #}
      {% set texto = item.content['#text']|striptags|slice(0, item.content['#text_summary_trim_length']) %}
      <p {{ attributes }}>{{ texto }}...</p>
    {% else %}
      <p {{ attributes }}>{{ item.content }}</p>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
...
```