# Limit the number of characters of Node Body(summary) in Search Results

Tags: search

In Drupal 8, I am using 'Search API' template file to display search results. My each page has more than 1000 words content. When I perform a search it display the results correctly, but I see the full content in search results.

I just want to display 20 to 30 characters just as it display with default Drupal 8 search.

Here is the Code of Search Results page template:

```
{{ form }}

{% if search_title %}
<div class="ps19cms-search-result-title">
  <h2>{{ search_title }}</h2>
</div>
{% endif %}

<div class="ps19cms-api-search-results">
{{ results }}
</div>

</div>
```

The content is printed with {{results}}. How Can I break it so that instead of printing full body summary text, it only prints 20-30 characters but only those which matches with the keyword.

Thanks

Comment: In your search view, you should be able to use the Summary or Trimmed formatter and limit the number of characters there.

Comment: Or if you need to do this in the twig template for some reason, see this answer:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/200318/78610

Comment: I have checked the above post, but if I apply slice function on text, then it will just show the characters of 1st result and hide the remaining results.

Comment: From indexer settings, I have select "Search results highlighting input" and it works fine. The only problem is that: It cannot highlight the text and do not show searched part of text in excerpts. It only shows first 30 characters. Any solution?